# Can Amazon Cloudwatch Logs Insights access json fields?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am trying to write json logs to CloudWatch, and I planned to access json fields in the log, like:

```
fields @timestamp, log.url, log.body ,log.error
| sort @timestamp desc
| filter log.error is string
| limit 500
```

And the logs are json strings like

```
{"url": "GET /foo", "body": "goo" "error": "hoo"}
```

I wish CloudWatch understand that my log entries are jsons, and I can do things with json fields, is that possible?

Comment: you should be able to use url as field name instead of log.url

Comment: Any update on this?